# PS Active Directory per user login count

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I've been looking for a solution but cannot find anything easy enough or reliable, so please excuse for bringing this up again.

In a typical AD environment, what I want to get is a monitoring report that would say something in the lines that "user X has logged in YYYY times in the past ZZ period".
The lastlogon date on get-aduser in PS is the only thing I can find, as that changes with each login, but cannot be easily scripted in a scheduled run to generate a report for eg.

Has anyone implemented this or use any tools that can track this?

Comment: What code have you tried? You'll generally gets better response on here if you show effort up to this point.

Answer (score 1):

There's only one reliable way to do what you want: collect and parse the audit logs from all Domain Controllers.

If you have a few users that you want to keep track of over time, an alternative could be monitoring the sum of the `logonCount` values for that user. Since the `logonCount` attribute is not replicated, you will have to collect it from each DC per user, then calculate the difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably check the AD replication logs for replication of changes to the `lastlogontimestamp` property.

[This script](http://bsonposh.com/archives/253) will do what you want for a particular user - closest I've managed to come so far.